# How to get sbteclipse working with Scala 2.9

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt

I am playing with the spray template project and Scala 2.9.0.1.

I want to work with Eclipse and so I've added the following lines to the build.sbt file
of the spray template project.

```
resolvers += {
  val typesafeRepoUrl = new java.net.URL("http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases")
  val pattern = Patterns(false, "    [organisation]/[module]/[sbtversion]/[revision]/[type]s/[module](-[classifier])-[revision].    [ext]")
  Resolver.url("Typesafe Repository", typesafeRepoUrl)(pattern)
}

libraryDependencies <<= (libraryDependencies, sbtVersion) { (deps, version) => 
   deps :+ ("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" %% "sbteclipse" % "1.3-RC2" extra("sbtversion" ->    version))
}
```

I always get this error:

com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse_2.9.0-1;1.3-RC2: not found

Of course the directory at the typesafe server does not exist. There is only:
http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse_2.8.1/
but sbt is trying to get:

http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse_2.9.0-1/0.10.1/1.3-RC2/jars/sbteclipse_2.9.0-1-1.3-RC2.jar

I figured out that 2.8.1 is the scala version sbt uses internaly. But my
sbt version (0.10) uses the scala version set in the build.sbt (scalaVersion := "2.9.0-1") to build the url to download sbteclipse.

Does anyone know how to set this up correctly? How do I tell the build.sbt file that I want to use Scala 2.9 but to look for the sbteclipse plugin at the correct URL?

Are there any plans to include something like sbteclipse to the sbt standard distribution? That would be more than welcome and probably help a lot of beginners with Scala, sbt and  Eclipse.

Claus

Answer (score 2):

try some thing like "com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse_2.8.1" % "1.3-RC2....." 
using "%%" will automicly  add scala version to the library name. using "%" will not.

Comment: Great! Mark my answer, can you?

Answer (score 0):

There is also a shorter way to get sbteclipse into use. Create a file `~/.sbt/plugins/plugins.sbt` with this content:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.0")
```